# How can I edit Joomla! menu?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I'm looking for a way to edit Joomla! menu or creating a custom menu for Joomla!(version 2.5), like add an element to each menu item.

I can edit modules from this path: `root\templates\beez_20\html\modules.php`

how can I edit menu source code ?

Comment: what kind of element do you want to add to your menu?

Comment: I want to add a `div` to sub menu with special position for display module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to edit the CSS, you could append a specific css class to your menu module in the Joomla! backend.

But if you want to add an element (i.e. change the code), you could for example just create your own module (http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module) and then "clone" the menu module (root/modules/mod_menu) by copying the contents to the respective files of your module.

Note that you would have to create a module package as explained in the link, then you'll be able to install it through the Joomla backend. When the custom menu module is installed, you can edit the way it looks by going to the folder root/modules/mod_*yourmenuname*/tmpl/default.php. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: actually this is not what I was looking for, but may be helpful. thanks